# mongodb database fileds are not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im trying to update the data , but its not updating in the database

but in console it is showing like this

[image]

Here is the code :

```
   exports.forgotPassword = async( req, res) =>{
     const { id, password } = req.body;

     const user = await  User.findOne({ _id : id })
        if (!user) {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: "User was not found"
          });
        }

    else {
     const userUpdatedPassword =  User.update({id}, {$set:{ password:encrypt(password), 
        updatedPasswordTime:new Date() }})
     
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "Upadted Sucessfully"
    });
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you put the wrong filter, you need to do `const userUpdatedPassword = await User.updateOne({_id: id}, {$set:{ password:encrypt(password), updatedPasswordTime:new Date() }})`, in addition you can await for result and print userUpdatedPassword to console to check if here updatedCount > 0.

Comment: updatedCount this field is not showing in console.log

Comment: could you send to me result from console.log ?

Comment: console file is very big

Comment: ` const userUpdatedPassword = await User.updateOne({_id: id}, {$set:{ password:encrypt(password), 
        updatedPasswordTime:new Date() }})
console.log(userUpdatedPassword);`

Should not be very big

Comment: i updated to  `update` with `updateOne` now its working . thanks!